# Opera browser set itself as default without asking!

Tags: debian, defaults, opera

I just downloaded `opera-stable_56.0.3051.99_amd64.deb` from https://www.opera.com/de/download

and ran

```
sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_56.0.3051.99_amd64.deb
```

It complained about some missing dependencies so I ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
```

then reran

```
sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_56.0.3051.99_amd64.deb
```

anyway, am worried about what evil that has done to my otherwise clean debian distribution and how to undo it. At the least it has replaced the firefox which used to launch from the icon at the bottom of xfce with itself.

Actually, the command under the button is:

```
exo-open --launch WebBrowser %u
```

..so no opera keyword.

How do I get it back to how it was and if necessary clean up anything else bad which it might have done?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and the accept: favour returned: question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When installing software, always use the same methodology to remove said software as you've installed it with...* (true on any OS) **0:-)**

Therefore it's always a good idea to install from Debian pre-packaged repositories until you have a bit more experience.  **;-)**

In this case, to uninstall opera:

```
sudo dpkg --remove opera-stable
```

to then get rid of any dependencies you now no longer need, run:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed, the button in xfce launches firefox again not opera. Also, a few worrying lines after the clean: `apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list` , `apt/trusted.gpg` , `cron.daily/opera-browser` how evil, opera created some kind of daily cron job.. why does a browser need a cron job?

Comment: Wow! (I never tried Opera, but noting now never to try...)  Danke für die extra Informationen! **;-)**

Comment: But why opera set itself as default without asking? :)

Comment: Because that's what the `.deb` package did??? @GAD3R  **:P ;-)**

Comment: @Fabby I think because its a `non-free` software , the defaut web browser is changed without asking the user for. Not sure about.

Comment: Just realised you can do `sudo apt install chromium chromium-l10n` and then `chromium` to get a browser which comes with the blessing of the debian package maintainers. not sure if it is FOSS but am more relaxed about using it.